FIO jump out and did not continue the runtime when ramp_time is reached
I met a problem on running FIO in Windows OS, below is the config I set:
[global]
ioengine=windowsaio
thread=32
overwrite=1
verify_fatal=1
verify_dump=1
do_verify=1
verify=crc32c-intel
time_based=1
readwrite=randwrite
runtime=1m
size=256m
ramp_time=10s
iodepth=32
bs=4k
verify_backlog=21845
verify_backlog_batch=21846
[QD_32_BS_4k]
directory=C\:\\fioTestDataFile

The FIO would only run 10 seconds and then jump out to command prompt, seems that the FIO only execute with ramp_time=10s, but if I remove the ramp_time=10s, the test would able to run 60s completely.
Please advise why it could not run 60s with ramp_time=10s, thanks.
Jacky
